# Issue in code while checking whether url is active or inactive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written a method in c#

```
     public static bool Test(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            resp.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It still displays "https://insurance.ky.gov/Home.aspx?Div_ID=2" url as a inactive url (false) and throws exception "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined." when url begins with "www" like  www.abc.com.

Please help me !!!

Comment: It is unlikely your code to fail the way you describe if you pass `url =  "https://insurance.ky.gov/Home.aspx?Div_ID=2"`. Please make sure to provide [MCVE] and use inline constants for all values.

Comment: If i add www, it still display it as false...

Comment: The code looks good, it should work. Have you tried with any other URL?